# check if user likes a page without application perm request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have a simple tab page, php sdk working and I know I can get the "like" for this specific page from the user signed_request.

This page is a colaboration with another company who also has an FB page. What i´d like to know is if I can get the like status of their page for the current user so I can authorize an action on this tab that is dependant of the user liking both my page and my partner´s.

Is this possible without using an actual app, an access_token and the appropriate perms requested?

e.g. my page is fb.com/Coke and my partner is fb.com/Target
On this specific tab page I want to enable a button only if me (Coke) is liked (which I can get already) and if my partner (Target) is also liked.

I tried the graphAPI (me/likes) and FQL (using the connection table) and both compalin of an unauthorized request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

No, this will not be possible in a production setting.

**Further explanation:**

Some users have their list of likes as public. In that case, it would work.

But in order to get likes from a user that has that setting as anything but public (such as myself, only friends of friends can see it), then it requires an app and an `access_token` that has a `user_likes` permission.

From the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan):

> ```
> Permissions Required:
> user_likes permissions if querying the current user.
> ```